# Javascript Password compliance

Tags: javascript, regex, passwords

I need the password to fulfill these requirements

1. Password must contain at least 8 word characters
2. Must have at least 1 numeric digit e.g. 3
3. Must have at least 2 uppercase characters but not in one consecutive sequence

It doesn't seems to work with this

```
 var pos = myPass.value.search(/^([\w.-]{8,})(?=.*\d)((.*?[A-Z]){2,})$/);
```

No.3 is the hardest.

Comment: Why this question is downvoted that much? Isn't that a valid question? I find the question quite challenging.

Comment: Should `SOmething here1` be failed? I think yes, but please clarify. Try `/^(?=\D*\d)(?=(?:(?:^|[^A-Z]+)[A-Z]){2}).{8,}$/.test(myPass.value)`. Or, if you plan to match only letters, digits, underscores, dots and hyphens, try `/^(?=\D*\d)(?=(?:(?:^|[^A-Z]+)[A-Z]){2})[\w.-]{8,}$/.test(myPass.value)`

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing consuming and non-consuming patterns adding limiting quantifiers to the consuming patterns that match a *sequence*, while you need to just *check* if a string matches some restrictive patterns or not. To add those restrictions you need *lookaheads*. `(?=.*\d)` *is* a correct part of your regex, other aren't.

Also, a `RegExp#test()` is a better method to check if a string matches or not.

Use

```
/^(?=\D*\d)(?=(?:(?:^|[^A-Z]+)[A-Z]){2}).{8,}$/.test(my‌​Pass.value)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gH9uM3/2)

Or, to allow only letters, digits, underscores, dots and hyphens in the password:

```
/^(?=\D*\d)(?=(?:(?:^|[^A-Z]+)[A-Z]){2})[\w.-]{8,}$/.test(my‌​Pass.value)
                                        ^^^^^^
```

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=\D*\d)` - after 0+ non-digits (`\D*`) at the start of the string, there must be a digit (`\d`) (note that after this lookahead execution, the regex index is still at the beginning of the string)
- `(?=(?:(?:^|[^A-Z]+)[A-Z]){2})` - there must be 2 sequences (`(?:...){2}`) of:

  - `(?:^|[^A-Z]+)` - start of string or one or more chars other than uppercase letters
  - `[A-Z]` - an uppercase letter.
- `.{8,}` - any 8 or more chars other than those used in a linebreak sequence

  OR
- `[\w.-]{8,}` - 8 or more ASCII letters and digits, underscores, dots or hyphens
- `$` - end of string.